# A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make a basic stop watch program but I keep getting this error "A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type"
Here's my Code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int ms, s, m, h;
        Timer timer1 = new Timer

        public Form1() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ms = 0;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ms = ms + 1;
            if (ms == 9)
            {
                ms = 0;
                s = s + 1;
                lblsecond.Text = s.ToString();
                if (s == 59)
                {
                    s = 0;
                    m = m + 1;
                    lblmin.Text = m.ToString();
                    if (m == 59)
                    {
                        m = 0;
                        h = h + 1;
                        lblhur.Text = h.ToString();
                        {
                            lblmsec.Text = ms.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ms = 0;
            h = 0;
            s = 0;
            m = 0;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            lblhur.Text = "00";
            lblmin.Text = "00";
            lblmsec.Text = "00";
            lblsecond.Text = "00";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Timer timer1 = new Timer(); and will work

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
```

You need to call the constructor of the class, when you create new class. Read some basics tutorials about C#. You are missing the basics !

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify which line is giving you the error? But also it might be this, why do you have {} around this?

```
                lblhur.Text = h.ToString();
                {
                    lblmsec.Text = ms.ToString();
                }
```

Or

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer
```

to

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
```

Comment: {
                    lblmsec.Text = ms.ToString();
                } // in this case is completely useless, but compile

Answer (score 0):

At the this line

```
  Timer timer1 = new Timer
```

end of Timer need () and ; ,like this:

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
```